# writeRaster if using the Chinese path occur error in the package of 'raster' in R language

Tags: r, raster

like this:

```
writeRaster(disater_r_mask, filename= "./实验/白银区_drought.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE) # need english path and filename
```

the error as follow:

> Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Dataset copy failed

when I change the path and filename into english the result is ok.
But, I want to use the Chinese path and filename.
how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10, vals=1:100)
x <- writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.tif")
#Error in .local(.Object, ...) : Unable to create dataset
```

"tif" is written via GDAL. Now with another (native) file format, it does not work either

```
y <- writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.grd")
Error in file(fnamevals, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(fnamevals, "wb") :
  cannot open file 'c:/temp/<U+5B9E><U+9A8C><U+767D><U+94F6><U+533A>.gri': Invalid argument
```

But that can be solved with

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale="Chinese")
```

Such that

```
y <- writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.grd")
y 

#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : c:/temp/实验白银区.grd 
#names       : layer 
#values      : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

Or NetCDF

```
z <- writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.nc", overwrite=TRUE)
#z
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : c:\temp\实验白银区.nc
```

To write GeoTIFF (or other formats via GDAL), you need to set the `Sys.setlocale` and add the option `"GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES"` when writing.

```
a <- writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.tif", options="GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES")
a 

#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#data source : c:/temp/实验白银区.tif 
#names       : 实验白银区 
#values      : 1, 100  (min, max)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  if added "Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale="Chinese") ", we can save it as chinese path and filename. but,this cannot save it as 'tif' et al. supported by GDAL. This is a problem. I want save it tif.

Comment: I have expanded my answer to show how that can be done

Comment: i try it.a <- writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.tif") is also ok.
because the path is not Chinese. If the path is Chinese, writeRaster cannot work. such as writeRaster(r, "./实验/实验白银区.tif") .

Comment: i try it.a <- writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.tif") is also ok.
because the path is not Chinese. If the path is Chinese, writeRaster cannot work. such as writeRaster(r, "./实验/实验白银区.tif") . Addtionally, use the writeRaster(r, "实验白银区.tif", options="GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES") , when i check it in the forder the filename is messy code even it is right show in the R console.